# Scaling for coordinate transformation

Tags: r, scale

I have a set of points in a rectangular space. The x-coordinates are scaled so that they are centered on 0:

```
#original points
x <- scale(runif(10000, min= 0, max= 1000), scale=FALSE)
y <- runif(10000, min= 0, max= 750)

plot(x, y, pch='.')
```

[image: plot_1]

I want to scale these points into a parabola, so that the x-values of points near `y= 0` are closer than x-values near `y= 750`, essentially warping the image:

```
#SC = scale
SC <- 0
x_scale = x * (y + SC)
y_scale = y * (y + SC)

plot(x_scale,y_scale, pch='.')
```

[image: plot_2]

Sometimes, however, I don't want a complete parabola. I want there to be a bit of a buffer:

```
SC <- 200 
x_scale_200 = x * (y + SC)
y_scale_200 = y * (y + SC)

plot(x_scale_200, y_scale_200, pch='.')
```

[image: plot_3]

As `SC` approaches infinity, the plotted space approaches the original rectangle:

```
SC <- 10000
x_scale_10k = x * (y + SC)
y_scale_10k = y * (y + SC)

plot(x_scale_10k, y_scale_10k, pch='.')
```

[image: plot_4]

I would like to create a variable `T`, that scales `SC` from 0 to 1. I essentially don't know how the degree of warping changes as `SC` gets larger.

In my mind, a function specifying `T = 0` would result in a parabola, where `T = 1` would result in a rectangle. I could just multiply `T` by 10,000 and use this (just making the assumption that the result is close enough to a rectangle), however the difference between `T = 0` and `T = 0.1` will be much larger than the difference between `T = 0.9` and `T = 1.0`. I'd like `T` to scale the degree of 'warping' linearly. Just a bit lost as to what the mathematical relationship of (a linear scaling) `T` to the warping might be and how to code that in here.

I considered posting this in the math forum, but think it is still appropriate enough for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I never solved this problem initially (turns out I didn't need to) I just happenned on this (4 years later) and the answer seemed apparent to me.

One solution would be to use the logit function to transform the input (in this case, 0.5 to 1 would need to used rather than 0 to 1, but this could be scaled as well. Since R doesn't like Inf (result of logit(1)), a small value has to be subtracted from 1. This is then scaled by 1000 (chosen based on some fiddling) to scale from parabola to rectangle.

```
sc_fun <- function(x)
{
  if (x == 1)
  {
    x1 <- x - 0.0000000000001
  } else {
    x1 <- x
  }
  SC <- boot::logit(x1) * 1000

  return(SC)
}

SC <- sc_fun(0.5)

x_scale_fun = x * (y + SC)
y_scale_fun = y * (y + SC)
plot(x_scale_fun, y_scale_fun, pch='.')

SC <- sc_fun(1)

x_scale_fun = x * (y + SC)
y_scale_fun = y * (y + SC)
plot(x_scale_fun, y_scale_fun, pch='.')
```